# *ngFor DOM not refreshing after callback

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

I've encontered a problem while developping an application using ASP.NET Core, Angular 5 and SignalR.

As a test, I made a simple chat app based on this sample : https://codingblast.com/asp-net-core-signalr-chat-angular/
But, when I modify the chat.component.ts file from

```
this.hubConnection.on('sendToAll', (nickname: string, message: string) => { this.messages.push(new Message(nickname, message)); });
// or this line
this.hubConnection.on('sendToAll', (nickname: string, message: string) => { this.addMessage(nickname, message); });
```

to

```
this.hubConnection.on('sendToAll', this.addMessage);
```

the DOM is not updated.

I've gone through step-by-step and I managed to figure out that when the callback arrives, it's actually another instance of the component... So every fields are undefined.

Here is the full component :

*chat.component.html*

```
<section class="card">
    <div class="card-body" *ngIf="messages !== undefined">
        <div *ngFor="let msg of messages">
            <strong>{{msg.nickname}}</strong>: {{msg.message}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
        <form class="form-inline" (ngSubmit)="sendMessage()" #chatForm="ngForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="nickname">Nickname</label>
                <input type="text" id="nickname" name="nickname" placeholder="Nickname" [(ngModel)]="nickname" required />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="message">Message</label>
                <input type="text" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your message" [(ngModel)]="message" required />
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-sm" type="submit" id="sendmessage" [disabled]="!chatForm.valid">Send</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

*chat.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HubConnection } from '@aspnet/signalr';
import { Message } from '../../models/message';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-chat',
    templateUrl: './chat.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./chat.component.css']
})
export class ChatComponent implements OnInit {
    private hubConnection: HubConnection;

    public nickname: string;
    public message: string;

    public messages: Message[];

    constructor() {
        this.messages = [];
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.hubConnection = new HubConnection('http://localhost:55233/chat');

        this.hubConnection.start().then(() => console.log('connection started')).catch(err => console.error(err));

        this.hubConnection.on('sendToAll', this.addMessage);
    }

    private addMessage(nickname: string, message: string): void {
        // this line is useful to avoid undefined error
        // due to the callback pointing to another instance of this component...
        if (this.messages === undefined) {
            this.messages = [];
        }

        this.messages.push(new Message(nickname, message));
    }

    public sendMessage(): void {
        this.hubConnection
            .invoke('sendToAll', this.nickname, this.message)
            .catch(err => console.error(err));
    }
}
```

Here is what I've tried :

- Putting public everywhere
- Getting rid of ngOnInit

How can I use this line `this.hubConnection.on('sendToAll', this.addMessage);` in this context?
Thanks for your help.

**EDIT** :
Thanks to Supamiu, here's the solution :

```
this.hubConnection.on('sendToAll', this.addMessage.bind(this));
```

Comment: To use addMessage with this context, use this.addMessage.bind(this).

Comment: @Supamiu it's working :) Have you a link to some kind of doc for this behavior?

Comment: @Supamiu would you mind creating an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript provides a tool to inject context into a method call: [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

You should change `this.addMessage` to `this.addMessage.bind(this)`.

Keep in mind that there's other solutions, like the one trichetriche explained, another one would be to change `addMessage` for an arrow function, as arrow functions keep `this` context:

```
private addMessage = (nickname: string, message: string) => {
    // this line is useful to avoid undefined error
    // due to the callback pointing to another instance of this component...
    if (this.messages === undefined) {
        this.messages = [];
    }

    this.messages.push(new Message(nickname, message));
}
```

By making this, you could still use `this.addMessage` without having to bind `this` context.

Answer (score 2):

```
this.hubConnection.on('sendToAll', this.addMessage);
```

Is the equivalent of

```
this.hubConnection.on('sendToAll', function(x) { this.addMessage(x); });
```

In javascript, you have to use closures when you write functions, or use the fat arrow. This would give

```
const that = this;
this.hubConnection.on('sendToAll', function(x) { that.addMessage(x); });
// or
this.hubConnection.on('sendToAll', x => { this.addMessage(x); });
```

Comment: Thanks for the info :) But I find the answer of @Supamiu more elegent : `this.addMessage.bind(this)`

Comment: Up to you, I was just explaining the issue !

Comment: Yeah, I'm gonna sleep less dump tonight :)